# Efficient way to merge array of objects with similar data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays that have a very large but unknown number of objects. For example:

```
const x = [
  {
    id:'apples',
    oldData: {
      min: 9,
      max: 50
    }
  },
  ...
]

const y = [
  {
    id:'bananas',
    newData: {
      min: 2,
      max: 60
    }
  },

  {
    id:'apples',
    newData: {
      min: 50,
      max: 200
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

I need to combine these so my result is something like:

```
const x = [
  {
    id:'apples',
    oldData: {
      min: 9,
      max: 50
    },
    newData: {
      min: 50,
      max: 200
    }
  },
  {
    id:'bananas',
    newData: {
      min: 2,
      max: 60
    }
  }
  ...
]
```

Note that apples is combined to include data from both arrays and bananas is add as a new element since it didn't have a match. Each array could have hundreds of values each so I found doing `.map()` and `Object.keys().map()` was really expensive.

Using ES6 and Lodash is imported.

Comment: If the id of each item is unique then you can use a map instead of an array for both datastructures. When you have a map, it's very easy to combine their data. 1/ map each fruit by id 2/ go through each keys of map1 and just add the data of map2 .You can then convert the data back to an array if you must. I think it is something you can do yourself without lodash.

Comment: @mpm I tried doing something similar by mapping the larges of the two, storing the id value, then checking for that id in the smaller array by mapping it. If the ids match I insert the larger object into the shorter location, other wise I push the data to the smaller array. Took *forever* to run.

Comment: `Took forever to run` needs benchmark. The lookup for a map in JS doesn't take forever even with hundreds of thousands of properties. And the solution you praised yourself below are exactly what I suggested.

Comment: Instead of asking us on how to do it (properly) you should show us your code so we can help you understand the problem and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following

```js
const x = [{id:'apples',oldData: {min: 9,max: 50}}];
const y = [{id:'bananas',newData: {min: 2,max: 60}},{id:'apples',newData: {min: 50,max: 200}}];

// Create an object with id as key and object as value
let obj = x.reduce((a,c) => Object.assign(a, {[c.id]:c}), {});
// Updating the value of object and adding new entries
y.forEach(v => {
  if(obj[v.id]) obj[v.id].newData = v.newData;
  else obj[v.id] = v;
});
// Getting the values in the object
console.log(Object.values(obj));
```

Comment: I like this. Let me translate it into my setup and see how this works out.

Comment: @dcp3450 - Sure. Let me know the results!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Fast too!

Comment: @dcp3450 You'll note that he has normalized the data first ;)   => `[c.id]:c`

Comment: @dcp3450 - Glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Creating a map is the way to go (one iteration per array):

```
const x = [ { id:'apples', oldData: { min: 9, max: 50 } } ];
const y = [
    { id:'bananas', newData: { min: 2,  max: 60  } },
    { id:'apples',  newData: { min: 50, max: 200 } }
];

let lookup = {};

//old
x.forEach(x_i => {
    lookup[x_i.id] = x_i;
});

//new
y.forEach(y_i => {
    if (y_i.id in lookup === false)
        lookup[y_i.id] = {};
    lookup[y_i.id].newData = y_i.newData;
});

console.log(lookup);
```

output:

```
{ apples:
   { id: 'apples',
     oldData: { min: 9, max: 50 },
     newData: { min: 50, max: 200 } },
  bananas: { newData: { min: 2, max: 60 } } }
```